# How to get color property of a picture object in powerpoint-VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am working on a CBIR (Context Image Retrieval) project, 
I am creating PowerPoint slides, that include many shapes and simple pictures(e.g sun, ball, chair..).
I'm using a VBA code to retrieve the COLOR(fill,background) feature of the object/shapes in the slide.

But, I can't get it for the pictures(jpeg/wmf) objects. 
How to retrieve the **picture's color** by VBA code? Since Clip Art is no longer available on PowerPoint, are there any other **picture libraries recognized by PowerPoint?**

Answer (score 2):

In the PowerPoint object model, pictures are seen as sort of collections of stuff that PowerPoint knows nothing about. You'd have to ungroup the picture (or a copy of it that you later delete) in order to retrieve colors from the individual shapes within the picture. That assumes that it's a vector picture and contains only vector shapes. You can't do much at all with a raster image w/o resorting to external libraries and more complex programming.