# How can you add one of PowerPoint's built in Icons with VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I don't see any methods in the PowerPoint Object Model to add one of PowerPoint's built in icons. I see the ability to add the built in shapes and pictures, but not icons?

How would you do it? Would it be best to just have a slide with the icons I want to use saved somewhere and just copy it off the slide?

Comment: >> Would it be best to just have a slide with the icons I want to use
That, or save the icons to a specific folder in an image format that PPT can insert.

Comment: It looks like when turning a PPTM (PowerPoint Macro Enabled) into a PPAM (PowerPoint Add-in) I can't save them with slides and I can't reference them in the VBA anyway it seems.

Comment: Correct; the PPTM can contain slides but a PPAM saved from your PPTM includes just the VBA content, none of the slides/masters/layouts/defaults. You could distribute both the PPAM and also a PPTX with the needed icons. A bit of extra code in the PPAM can return the path to the folder where the PPAM is installed, and you could then open the PPTX from there.

Comment: Thanks @SteveRindsberg. I think since our organization has a SharePoint Online site I am going to just save a PPTX file onto that site and just reference that file. From some testing it looks like I can use internet URIs instead of local file paths to insert slides and other objects on slides.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg that's exactly what I am trying to do: I put an icon in slide ` 1 that I would like to copy and paste to certain parts of a slide, but I cannot get a way to reference to it. Is it not possible then, unless they are selected manually?

Comment: @Bradipo It would be better to ask a new question with a more detailed description of what you're after than to ask it as a comment on this thread.

Comment: I will, but basically I wanted to take a vector icon from slide (without selecting it) and copy/paste another ones but i could not get a way to point to it, so I had to resort to uploading it from a folder. You seem to say something similar in this other question, although for raster images. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41146499/18247317

Answer (score 1):

It seems that upon looking into the problem further PowerPoint does not have the ability to insert its built in icons using VBA. Additionally, when creating a PPAM file from a PPTM you lose all slides, masters, layouts, etc.

The best way to insert slides or objects on slides is to just create another PPTX file and store it on SharePoint, a share drive, or just distribute a file with your add-in so that you can reference the slides and objects on the slides in your add-in.

The [Slides.InsertFromFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slides.insertfromfile) method requires a filename and index. The filename is a string and while the example shows a local resource I have tested and it also works with an internet URI (specifically tried a SharePoint resource, but I could do further testing if needed).